# Django Rest update many to many field of multiple objects at once

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on chat app django rest backend. Btw I have a problem to update m2m field of multiple objects at once.
Inside the `Message` model there is an m2m field `deleted` which represents a list of users who deleted this message.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    # other fields  
    deleted = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

So I can implement the delete functionality by adding user inside that field when user deletes a specific message.
But the problem is when user deletes a conversation(all messages in it), how can I implement to update the `delete` field of multiple `Message` objects at once. Because each object has empty `delete` field, another user inside `delete` field, or same user inside `delete` field(means that user already deleted a message before).

**Edit**

According to validname's comment I'm adding an example to make clear about my problem.

Please imagine user1 and user2 has conversation1 and there are 3 messages inside that conversation. So currently message list of that conversation is like following:

```
[
  {
    id: 304,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: []
  },
  {
    id: 305,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: [2] // user2 already deleted this message before
  },
  {
    id: 306,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: [1] // user1 already deleted this message before
  },
]
```

And user2 just has deleted conversation1, so after that message list should be like following:

```
[
  {
    id: 304,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: [2]
  },
  {
    id: 305,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: [2] // no need to change for existing user2
  },
  {
    id: 306,
    conversation: 1,
    ...
    deleted: [1, 2] // insert user2
  },
]
```

I just want a django function that works like above changes.

Comment: So do you have trouble of finding all messages in conversation or just adding them to delete list, what did you attempt to do

Comment: I just have a problem on adding to delete list of all messages in one queryset

Comment: So, once again, you have a queryset of messages and some user, and you want to add this user to 'deleted' of every message? Is that correct?

Comment: You're right, btw the problem is just saving the old value of `deleted` field in every message objects. For example, in the conversation of user1 and user2, there are 3 messages. The old `deleted` fields are just [], [1], and [2]. If user2 is just deleted the conversation, I want to get values as [2], [1,2] and [2]. Hope this example is helpful for your understand

Comment: I don't get what the 'old deleted' means and these conditions may look like separate question. I recommend you to edit your post and add clear scenario such as 'I have X, and i want Y', as i paraphrased your post in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

All m2m relations are implemented by extra table and have their own models which are accessible by field's [thorough](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) attribute.

So if you have a set of messages and you want to add user to 'deleted' for each of message, you can do it by bulk creating records for though model:

```py
from itertools import cycle

message_qs = ...  # Query set of message.
user = ...  # User model instance.

# Construct list of [(message_1, user), (message_2, user), ...] etc.
data = list(zip(message_qs, cycle(user)))

# Transform data to through model instances to pass to bulk create.
through_model = Message.deleted.through
instances = [
    through_model(message=m, user=u) for m, u in data
]

through_model.objects.bulk_create(instances)
```

This is supposed to be very efficient way. However if you don't care about efficiency at the moment, you can just iterate over each user and call message.deleted.add(user) for each.